# Obtain a data frame using write.table without initial part of every row in R

Tags: r, file, dataframe, write.table

I have a data frame in which rows are like this: xyz-1; xyz-2; and so on

data frame x:

```
      1 2 3
xyz-1 1 4 e
xyz-2 2 5 a
xyz-3 3 6 c
```

I tried `write.table(x,file="out")`; `x` is my data frame. When i use `write.table`, i want the text file (output) whose rows are in the form: 1;2;...;

How can i do this? How can i remove the initial part of every row (xyz)?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "xyz - " part with: `rownames(x) <- NULL`.

Alternative: `rownames(x) <- gsub("xyz-", "", rownames(x))`
This replaces "xyz-" with "" (nothing) so it removes it.

Make sure the pattern is "xyz-" exactly, or if you need a space somewhere (like "xyz -").

Comment: Yes, but the row name is xyx-1 or xyz-a, i want to remove only the first part of the name

Comment: @GuglielmoC. I edited my answer. I have not tried it out myself but it should work. Let me know if something is wrong!